# How to implement Update/Delete operations using Business Data Web part

Tags: web-part, bcs

I have created a web part page for displaying the contents of my external list with a **Filter** parameter. I'm using a **Business Data List Web part** for this. I need to have **Update/Delete** operations for the same. How can I achieve this.

**Note:-** In the External Content type, I've *Read List and Read Item* operations defined on the SQL Stored Procedure and Create/Update/Delete on the tables directly.